# What are Starseeds

Tags: larry-niven, known-space

I'm currently reading *Juggler of Worlds* by Niven & Lerner. I have read, a while ago, all the Ringworld books and a few other *Known Space*, so I remember that

> the Puppeteers used a Starseed lure to get Outsiders to the humans so they could obtain the hyperdrive technology and defeat the Kzinti.

However, now that I ran into them again in *Jugglers of Worlds*, I am at a loss as to what Starseeds actually are.

What are Starseeds?
And was this explained somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The true nature of starseeds is only revealed a bit later, near the end of *Juggler of Worlds*.

> Starseeds are actually baby Outsiders.

Comment: I missed that detail.  Now I have to go re-read to find that detail.

Comment: @geoffc If you don't feel like re-reading the whole thing (I find *Juggler* a bit boring if you read Beowulf's stories before) it's in chapter 73, when Sigmund goes strike a deal with Fourteen.

Comment: Thanks!   Re-Read that part.  I found Juggler a fun retelling (ala Enders Game from Bean's perspective) with enough new content tying it all together to make it fun.  But I spent alot of time saying. I've read this before.